# < styled component > property disappearing after gatsby serve

Tags: image, gatsby, styled-components

I'm using < styled components > for my gatsby site, everything is working fine except one detail: border-radius is not applied to Img after I "gatsby serve". Any ideas?

```
const Headshot = styled(Img)`
   box-shadow: 0 0.7em 1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-radius:100%;
`
```

This shows when inspecting the img on "gatsby develop":

```
.gttwKy {
    box-shadow: 0 0.7em 1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

This shows when inspecting the img on "gatsby serve":

```
.lnclJt {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 0.7em 1em 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi surrriam, we'll need a [minimal reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this!

Comment: hi derek, sorry for the super late reply. I had an error related to the < styled component > installation - reinstalling the plugin fixed the issue.